# How to fix Error Code E1696? In Windows Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, stdafx.h

So I recently downloaded Windows Visual Studio 2019. I haven't programmed in a while and I wanted to refresh myself with a basic "hello world" program. But for some reason I'm getting an error with my Stdafx.h header. The error code is E1696 "cannot open source file "stdafx.h"" anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The default precompiled header in Visual Studio used to be `stdafx.h`. Since then, the default name has been changed to `pch.h`, and later precompiled headers became disabled by default. Simply remove the `#include "stdafx.h"` or change it to `#include "pch.h"` depending on your precompiled header settings. If you don't need precompiled headers, you can disable it.

Comment: Simply disable precompiled headers would be my advice.